# 3D tensor subsetting operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I'm trying to perform a specific operation on a 3D tensor. I'll just show it below using a 3D numpy array instead. Basically I want to do the same operation as below but on an equivalent tensor.

```
a3 = np.array([[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]], [[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]], [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]])

expression = (a3.sum(axis=(1,2)) >= 1)

a3[expression, :, 1].flatten()
```

It should return a list of the same length as the first dimension of the initial 3D tensor.

I've tried to write some code based on tf.constant, but it has not worked so far. Here's my attempt:

```
a3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(a3)
one = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)
mask = tf.keras.backend.greater_equal(tf.keras.backend.sum(a3,axis=(1,2)),one)
tf.boolean_mask(a3,mask,axis=0)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

with sess.as_default():
    assert tf.compat.v1.get_default_session() is sess
    print(a3.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out:

```
a3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(a3)
one = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)
mask = tf.keras.backend.greater_equal(tf.keras.backend.sum(a3,axis=(1,2)),one)
a4masked = tf.boolean_mask(a3,mask,axis=0)
a4flat = tf.reshape(a4masked, [tf.size(a4masked)])

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

with sess.as_default():
  assert tf.compat.v1.get_default_session() is sess
  print(a4flat.eval())
```